# I want to display two nodes overlapping each other with ARKit

Tags: swift, arkit, scnnode

Two nodes,
The text and board are separated.
I want the board to be the background for the text.

Is something wrong?

I referred to [this site](https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?anno=2&depth=1&hl=ja&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=en&sp=nmt4&tl=ja&u=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47073334/scntext-background-speech-bubble&xid=17259,15700023,15700186,15700191,15700256,15700259,15700262,15700265&usg=ALkJrhitVJhfYf0VmFZbZkEAUR_0PfqHsg)!

```swift
let housenode = SCNNode()
```

Method to create a text node

```
//TextNode
private func addTextToTheWorld() -> SCNNode{

    let text = SCNText(string: "Hello", extrusionDepth: 0.5)
    let font = UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 2)
    text.font = font
    text.alignmentMode = CATextLayerAlignmentMode.center.rawValue
    text.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
    text.firstMaterial?.specular.contents = UIColor.white
    text.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
    text.chamferRadius = 0.01
    let (minBound, maxBound) = text.boundingBox
    let textNode = SCNNode(geometry: text)
    textNode.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation( (maxBound.x - minBound.x)/2, minBound.y, 0.02/2)
    textNode.scale = SCNVector3Make(0.1, 0.1, 0.1)
    textNode.position = SCNVector3(0.1, 0.1, -0.1)

    return textNode
}
```

Method to create a board node

```
//PanelNode
private func addPanelToTheWorld(node:SCNNode) -> SCNNode{

    let (min, max) = (node.boundingBox)
    let w = CGFloat(max.x - min.x)
    let h = CGFloat(max.y - min.y)

    let boxGeo = SCNBox(width: w * 1.1, height: h * 1.1, length: 0, chamferRadius: 0)
    boxGeo.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.blue
    let box = SCNNode(geometry: boxGeo)
    //box.scale = SCNVector3Make(0.1, 0.1, 0.1)
    box.position = SCNVector3(0.1, 0.1, -0.1)
    //scene.rootNode.addChildNode(box)
    return box
}
```

Method to place a node

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let sphereNode = addTextToTheWorld()
    sphereNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
    let panelNode = addPanelToTheWorld(node:sphereNode)
    sphereNode.addChildNode(panelNode)
    housenode.addChildNode(sphereNode)

    let infrontCamera = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, -0.3)

    guard  let cameraNode = sceneView.pointOfView else {
        return
    }

    let pointInWorld = cameraNode.convertPosition(infrontCamera, to: nil)

    var screenPosition = sceneView.projectPoint(pointInWorld)

    guard let location : CGPoint = touches.first?.location(in: sceneView) else{
        return
    }
    screenPosition.x = Float(location.x)
    screenPosition.y = Float(location.y)
    let finalPostion = sceneView.unprojectPoint(screenPosition)
    housenode.eulerAngles = cameraNode.eulerAngles
    housenode.position = finalPostion

    self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(housenode)

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding the panelNode as a child node of your text here:

```
sphereNode.addChildNode(panelNode)
```

This means that the position you set inside your `addPanelToTheWorld()` function is relative to the text node.

A quick fix to put the board at the right position would be to change that relative position. For instance, inside `addPanelToTheWorld()` change

```
box.position = SCNVector3(0.1, 0.1, -0.1)
```

to

```
box.position = SCNVector3(w/2, h, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
I wrote the source according to the advice and it worked!

I was so in trouble that I was saved!